# undefined symbols for architecture armv7s

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4.2

When i build my old version app ios 4.3 i have this warning

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SSSwitch", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in LoginViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SSHUDView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ContractorInfoViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in ContractorListViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in EvenementBilleterieViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in EvenementCoupDeCoeurViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in EvenementRequestViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in GourmetCoupDeCoeurViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in GourmetRequestViewController.o
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

please help me

Comment: Muncken is right : SSToolKit (http://sstoolk.it) does not seem to be linked with the current project. They explain on their homepage how to link with libSSToolkit.a.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linker errors usually mean that you are trying to access code from a library or similar that is not linked against. In your case it looks like an SS lib of some kind is accessed, but not linked against. Make sure that any potential libraries are added to the project by selecting the project in File Navigator, and then selecting:

```
Target -> Build Phases -> Link binary with libraries
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: i have this problem just when i build my app for my device. it work in simulator

Comment: @user1781040 then please check if you forget to add something into "Compile Sources" in the same place

Answer (score 2):

Remove `armv7s` from `valid architectures` section and it will work.

**Build Settings --> Architectures --> Valid Architectures**

[image: Xcode Build Settings]

Comment: how to remove. should we just delete??

Comment: I am not the one who asked the question. So i dont have option to accept your answer.Answer can be accepted only by the person who asked the question. I was just browsing through and found your answer helpful.Thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

Whenever this happens go into the .m of offending class and CMD + Click on the class named indicated in the error. This will take you in the header of the library you need to add. Now you'll know what library is missing and you can add it to the project.